# case_when is slow when embedding in an aggregation function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using data.table to manipulate data with a lot of rows, but I am seeing significant slowdowns when I try to use case_when with an aggregate function. I have found that I can do 2 different data.table steps , first to create a new column using my case_when statement, and then do the second step of aggregating that variable and it performs very fast, but I dont always want to have to create the variable in an initial data.table step. Is there a better way of using a 'case_when' type statement with an aggregating data.table step?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table('id' = 1:283408,
                 'year' = 2018,
                 'qtr' = sample(x = 1:4,283408,TRUE),
                 'var1' = sample(x = 1:12,size = 283408,TRUE))


##### This approach takes me 66 seconds
start <- proc.time()
df2 = df[,
         list(var2 = max(case_when(var1 <= 3 ~ 3,
                                   var1 <= 6 ~ 6,
                                   var1 <= 9 ~ 9,
                                   TRUE ~ 12))),
         by = list(id,year,qtr)]
proc.time() - start

##### This approach takes .11 seconds
start <- proc.time()
df[,var2 := case_when(var1 <= 3 ~ 3,
                      var1 <= 6 ~ 6,
                      var1 <= 9 ~ 9,
                      TRUE ~ 12)]
df2 = df[,
         list(var2 = max(var2)),
         by = list(id,year,qtr)]
proc.time() - start
```

Comment: I'm very curious to see what answers you get.  I have found that for some row operations doing it as a data.frame improves time significantly.

Comment: Although I don't know why there is such a big difference between the two approaches, you might want to rethink your example: currently the `max`-operation is redundant because you are working rowwise as a result of using `id` in the `by`-statement.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the difference in run time is because in your first approach, you execute `case_when` for each single row (!), i.e. 283408 times, whereas in the second example, it is run only once.

Comment: N being the number of groups. In first case you run `max` AND `case_when` N times. In second example you run `case_when` 1 time and `max` N times. @docendodiscimus was on the right track.